# Where does the trained data get stored after fit() is called in ml?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am new to machine learning without much experience in python.

In the following code, where does the trained data get stored after we called `fit()` and how does it know if the data is trained or not after calling `predict()` method.

I know this might be a stupid question but some help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
#Fitting Simple linear regression to the training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) 

#Predicting the Test search results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: your predict() call will fail if model is not trained on you data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fit()` function simply fits a Linear Model to your data. The training data is already assigned to your variable `X_train` (features) and `y_train` (labels) therefore no training data is being stored after calling `fit()`. You can however, save the trained/fitted model that includes the parameters that have been approximated using the training data.

Coming to your second question now, it is impossible to predict before fitting a model to your data. If you attempt to call `predict()` before calling `fit()` you'll get a [`NotFittedError`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError.html):

> Exception class to raise if estimator is used before fitting.
>
> This class inherits from both ValueError and AttributeError to help
>   with exception handling and backward compatibility.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> >>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
> >>> from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError
> >>> try:
> ...     LinearSVC().predict([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
> ... except NotFittedError as e:
> ...     print(repr(e))
> NotFittedError("This LinearSVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with
> appropriate arguments before using this estimator."...)
> ```

Comment: So does fitting the Linear model to the data means it just provides it with the algorithm and it trains it at the same time? And does X_train change after we call fit()?

Comment: Fitting a Linear model simply means that you attempt to approximate the parameters of the Linear Model such that you can make good enough predictions on new, unseen data. This is also called model training, yes. `X_train` does not change when calling `fit()`.

Answer (score 2):

The data doesn't get stored at all. It's used to fix the parameters of your linear Regression, that's all.

This is why it's super important to split your data (train, test) before looking at the performance of your model. Because when you call the `fit()` method, your linear regression will not check if the data is similar to the on that was used to train it. It will just predict an output

To split your data beforehand you can use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`

Answer (score 1):

The data used to train the model doesn't get stored. The trained model can be saved. Use joblib.dump or pickle.dump (pickle have to be imported separately.)